# Plotting cicle using ListPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

How can I plot circle plot with ListPlot function or how to organize data to produce circle plot from ListPlot function ?

If u do something like this

```
ListPlot[Tuples[{{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {-3, 3}}]]
```

i get

```
{{0, -3}, {0, 3}, {1, -3}, {1, 3}, {2, -3}, {2, 3}, {3, -3}, {3, 
  3}, {4, -3}, {4, 3}, {5, -3}, {5, 3}}
```

function value in this example is constant, and we ll see two straight lines.

but, when i need to plot circle, i have two y points per x and they are changing,

so i want plot list plot, i must have data like this:

```
{{0, f1[0]}, {0, f2[0]}, {1, f1[1]}, {1, f2[1]}, {2, f1[2]}, {2, f2[2]}, {3, f1[3]}, {3,f2[3]}, {4, f1[4]}, {4, f2[4]}, {5, f1[5]}, {5, f2[5]}}
```

where f1 is y1 and f2 is y2 and

```
yn = {-Sqrt[R - x^2], Sqrt[R - x^2]}
```

or, i can make data like this

```
in = Function[x, {x, (-Sqrt[25 - #1^2]) &[x], (Sqrt[25 - #1^2]) &[x]}] /@ 
 Range[-5, 5, 1/2]
out = {{-5, 0, 0}, {-(9/2), -(Sqrt[19]/2), Sqrt[19]/2},.....
```

where  we have `{x1,y1,y2}`, but List plot dosent work with this data

So, How can i plot this?

Comment: Are you aware of `ListPolarPlot`? If so, why do you want to use `ListPlot`. Also, instead of Pythagoras, you can easily generate `x` and `y` from the `Cos` and `Sin` of the angle.

Comment: p.s. `CirclePoints`.

Comment: Following up on @Kuba's comment, try this: `ListPlot[CirclePoints[100], AspectRatio -> Automatic]`. It's a pretty compact way of doing what you ask. Notice the `AspectRatio` directive in order to produce an undistorted circle.

Comment: Building up on the comments above this one: `Manipulate[
 ListPlot[CirclePoints[i]
  , AspectRatio -> Automatic
  , PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}
  , ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[i, {0, 100}]] &)
  , Epilog -> {Text[Style[
      ColorData["Rainbow"][N@Rescale[i, {1, 100}]], 20], {0.5, 0.5}]}
  ]
 , {{i, 20}, 1, 100, 1}
 ]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
    ListPlot[Table[{Cos[a], Sin[a]}, {a, 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.05}], 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

with the effect of

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks, am soo bad at Table, can u tell me how to vary 'a' in ListPointPlot3D[
 Table[{5 Cos[fi], 5 Sin[fi], **a**}, {fi, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/180}]]  to produce cylindrical surface

Comment: @Gelios `Table` takes more than one iterator as well. Try this for example: `ListPointPlot3D[Flatten[Table[{5 Cos[fi], 5 Sin[fi], a}, {fi, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/180}, {a, -1, 1, 0.1}], 1]]`, which returns [this plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YMd0k.png).

Comment: I see, it works, but i concerned more about data representation, i'm trying threat coordinates line a сartesian product of set(str. line and circle produces cylindrical surf.). And If i use your answer i obtain just work solution with ListPointPlot3D, but if i try this ` MatrixForm@
 Table[{5 Cos[fi], 5 Sin[fi], a}, {fi, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/180}, {a, -1, 1, 
   0.1}]`  it dosent make clear sence, whereas  ` MatrixForm@Table[{5 Cos[fi], 5 Sin[fi], a}, {fi, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/180}] ` is pretty good, but 'a' should changing after one cycle and i can achieve this using AppenTo and For, but It does not look good

Comment: excuse me, all ok with your solution.

Comment: @Gelios  `MatrixForm` is for visualization only, not for further calculation or plotting.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, it will give you the circle:
`ListPlot[Table[{R Cos[fi],R Sin[fi]},{fi,0,2Pi,Pi/180}],AspectRatio->1]`